# Identifying the symmetry of a polar function

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

What is the purpose of $1+\cos(-\theta) \neq -r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they check symmetry about the $y$-axis in two different ways:

- by verifying if $r(-\theta)=-r(\theta)$;
- by verifying if $r(\pi-\theta)=r(\theta)$.

> What is the purpose of $1+\cos(-\theta) \neq -r$

So this refers to the first of the two above.

Side note: where is the argument about the symmetry with respect to the origin? They conclude *"therefore not symmetric about the origin"* but I would expect something like verifying whether  $r(\theta+\pi) = r(\theta)$ to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: Thanx friend, will you please show me how to prove that$ r=\sin (\theta /2)$ is symmetric about both the axis?